# How to fix Telethon error: Connection to Telegram failed 5 time(s)

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon

I have a robot. which is listening 3 Telegram channels in eternal mode. Sometimes it works as it should (eternally), but sometimes I caught mistakes.
Such as:

> Automatic reconnection failed 5 time(s)Future exception was never
> retrievedfuture: <Future finished
> exception=ConnectionError('Connection to Telegram failed 5
> time(s)')>ConnectionError: Connection to Telegram failed 5 time(s)

Before it, I usually gets

> Attempt to connect 1, Attempt to connect 2 and etc

Why does it happen?
My code is:

```
import config
from telethon import events, TelegramClient
from datetime import date, datetime

client = TelegramClient("NEW", config.TELEGRAM_ID, config.TELEGRAM_HASH)

def start():
    client.start()
    client.run_until_disconnected()

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=("names_of_channels")))
async def normal_handler_coinbase(event):
    data = event.message.message 
start()
```

As I said, sometimes it works properly: can work for a week without a reset and get new messages. But sometimes it fails in a few hours with the error I mentioned in the begining.